# Is there a way to calculate lg on a scientific calculator?

Tags: logarithms, calculator

Taking introduction to algorithms for computer science this semester and wanted to know if there is a way to calculate lg on scientific calculator? Thank you.

Comment: More often as "ln"

Comment: I think $\lg$ is referring to $\log_2$, if we're talking computer science. In which case $\log_b(x) = \frac{\log x}{\log b}$.

Comment: lg is a different form of log I'm assuming, I've encountered for first time in this class. I'm aware there are ways to calculate log and ln. But I'm specifically wondering for lg.

Comment: Often times, it doesn't even really matter which log it is.  In terms of ordering functions using Big-Oh and little-oh notation, they all act similarly to one another.  But yes, compsci usually uses `log` or `lg` to be the base-2 logarithm due to the high importance on binary systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$lg(x) = \dfrac{\log x}{\log 2}$

where $\log$ is log base anything that is allowed.

Comment: That works. But I'm assuming there is no function specific on the calculator? Thank you.

Comment: It depends on which calculator.  Some of the fancier calculators could have a button that lets you take a specific base for a logarithm without having to remember this identity.

Comment: A scientific calculator without a log or ln key. Really?

Comment: @JMoravitz. Yeah something like $log_ba$.

Comment: No no. I was specifically asking for lg form of logarithm. It certainly does have both log and ln functions.

Comment: Gotcha. Never seen one.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: In scientific calculator $\ln x=\log_{e} x$ & $\log x=\log_{10} x$

Logarithms is defined for positive real numbers, hence in general log can be calculated as follows   $$\log_{a}(b)=\frac{\log b}{\log a}$$

Answer (score 0):

The WP-34s,
an offshoot of the
HP-30 calculator,
*has* a LG button.
See the picture here:
http://kk.org/cooltools/wp-34s-scientific-calculator/

You can buy it here:
http://commerce.hpcalc.org/34s.php

To quote that site,
"The WP 34S is the most powerful scientific (non-graphing) calculator on the market. It is not an HP product, but it is rather a community-created product based on an existing HP calculator platform."

A simulation of it is available
for iPhone and iPad on
iTunes.